# Why is TechTalk SpecFlow plugin not available in MonoDevelop V5.2?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, monodevelop, specflow

For testing purposes I want to use TechTalk SpecFlow in MonoDevelop V5.2. Inside the [documentation](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Install-IDE-Integration/) I found it's possible to integrate with MonoDevelop, but I cannot find the plugin in the add-on manager. After a while I found that the SpecFlow plugin was not released for MonoDevelop V5.2.

http://addins.monodevelop.com/Project/Index/4

Is there another new plugin for SpecFlow or is there something to get SpecFlow working?

Thanks a lot,
Jordy